# UINavigationBarItem programmatically

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have view controller which is inherited from `UINavigationController`.
On `viewDidLoad` I want to set `rightBarButtonItem`.
I do following.

```
UINavigationItem* navItem = self.navigationItem;
UIButton* btnOptionsView = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[btnOptionsView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"options.png"]
                forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnOptionsView sizeToFit];
UIBarButtonItem* btnOptions = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnOptionsView];
navItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnOptions;
```

but the button is invisible, in debug mode I have noticed that `btnOptions.width` is 0, and also I can't set the title for `navItem`, something like this

```
[navItem setTitle:@"title"]
```

does not change the title of `UINavigationItem`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not subclassing UINavigationController. From apple documentation:

> The UINavigationController class implements a specialized view
>   controller that manages the navigation of hierarchical content. This
>   class is not intended for subclassing. Instead, you use instances of
>   it as-is in situations where you want your application’s user
>   interface to reflect the hierarchical nature of your content.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the title of the button